# Integer Part Equations...again

Tags: integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

This is a plea for readers solutions!

Solve $[20 \, x−3] = [15 \, x + 27]$, where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$.

I have my solution which is spread over five intervals and can solve any $[a \, x+b] = [c \, x + d]$ if $a,b,c,d$ are known integers.

What I wish to do is set down a general solution for integer $a, b, c, d, ....$ this is proving 'awkward'. So, I would welcome readers methods to solve the equation in order that it may furnish me with ideas for a general solution. The number of intervals in which the solutions lie varies depending on the values of $a, b, c, d$.

Comment: in any case you need $|5x-30| < 1$ so $x$ is near $6,$  between $\frac{29}{5}$ and $\frac{31}{5}$

Comment: Can you add the work you did and the solution you arrived at, so we can understand how you solved this?

Comment: my solution to [20x-3]=[15x+27] involved drawing four lines (y=20x-4, y=20x-3, y=15x+26 and y=15x+27) then identifying the region where these lines overlap. Next I found the coordinates of the extreme points of the overlap region and identified intervals of x which are inside this region and which satisfy the original equation (I did this by tabulating the results on my calculator). This gave rise to five intervals: 117/20-88/15, 59/10-89/15, 119/20-121/20, 91/15-61/10, 92/15-123/20. In each interval the lower value is permissable but the upper is not.

Comment: You might wanna put that comment into your question. Its hurting my eyes X_X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lfloor 20x−3 \rfloor = \lfloor 15x + 27 \rfloor$$

Let's start by wondering if there is a solution where $20x-3$ and $15x + 27$ are both integers. If that were the case, then we would get

\begin{align}
   20x−3 &= 15x + 27 \\
   5x &= 30 \\
   x & = 6
\end{align}

This is the union of these sets
\begin{align}
\end{align}

And we see that $20x-3 = 15x + 27 = 117$, so both sides are both equal to the integer $117$.

So lets move our origin to the point $x=6$.

Let $x = t+6$. Then we get

\begin{align}
   \lfloor 20x−3 \rfloor &= \lfloor 15x + 27 \rfloor \\
   \lfloor 20t+120−3 \rfloor &= \lfloor 15t + 90 + 27 \rfloor \\
   \lfloor 20t+117 \rfloor &= \lfloor 15t + 117 \rfloor \\
   \lfloor 20t \rfloor + 117 &= \lfloor 15t \rfloor + 117 \\
   \lfloor 20t \rfloor &= \lfloor 15t \rfloor
\end{align}

Let $n$ be an integer. Then

$\lfloor 15t \rfloor = n 
 \implies  n \le 15t < n + 1 
 \implies \frac{n}{15} \le t \lt \frac{n+1}{15} $
$\lfloor 20t \rfloor = n 
 \implies  n \le 20t < n + 1 
 \implies \frac{n}{20} \le t \lt \frac{n+1}{20}$

For non negative $n$,  the intersection
$$\bigg[\frac{n}{20}, \frac{n+1}{20}\bigg) \cap 
 \bigg[\frac{n}{15}, \frac{n+1}{15}\bigg)
= \bigg[\frac{n}{15}, \frac{n+1}{20}\bigg)$$
must be non empty.

This will work until

\begin{align}
   \frac{n}{15} &\ge \frac{n+1}{20} \\
   20n &\ge 15n + 15 \\
   n &\ge 3
\end{align}

For negative $n$, the interserction
$$\bigg[\frac{n}{15}, \frac{n+1}{15}\bigg) \cap 
 \bigg[\frac{n}{20}, \frac{n+1}{15}\bigg)
 = \bigg[\frac{n}{20}, \frac{n+1}{15}\bigg)$$
must be non empty.

This will work until

\begin{align}
   \frac{n}{20} &\ge \frac{n+1}{15} \\
   15n &\ge 20n + 20 \\
   n &\le -4
\end{align}

So the solution set is
$$\bigcup_{n=-3}^{-1}\left[6+\frac{n}{20}, 6+\frac{n+1}{15} \right)
 \cup \bigcup_{n=0}^{2}\left[6+\frac{n}{15}, 6+\frac{n+1}{20} \right)
$$

This is the union of these six intervals

\begin{array}{l}
   \left[6-\frac{3}{20}, 6-\frac{2}{15} \right) \\
   \left[6-\frac{2}{20}, 6-\frac{1}{15} \right)\\
   \left[6-\frac{1}{20}, 6               \right)\\
   \left[6+\frac{0}{15}, 6+\frac{1}{20} \right) \\
   \left[6+\frac{1}{15}, 6+\frac{2}{20} \right) \\
   \left[6+\frac{2}{15}, 6+\frac{3}{20} \right)
\end{array}

Comment: I don't understand your solution set's notation. Could you put a link to that?

Comment: @Mastermind817: I rewrote it. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for that solution. It is similar to my method but a lot more elegant and useful. I have used your method to solve a few other equations. Now I am moving onto quadratics with the floor function !